# How to update a nested key containing a dot?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

In a document like this:

```
[
  {
    a: "",
    b: 1,
    "createdAccounts": {
      "test@gmail.com": {
        "id": ["a", "b", "c"]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'm querying an email as:

```
    const email = "test@gmail.com"
    let account = await db.collection("users").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$project": {
                "createdAccounts": {
                    "$objectToArray": "$createdAccounts"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "createdAccounts.k": email
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "createdAccounts": {
                    "$arrayToObject": "$createdAccounts"
                }
            }
        }
    ]).toArray().then(results =>
    {
        const document = results[0];
        if (document && document.createdAccounts)
            return document.createdAccounts[email];        
        return null; 
    })
```

I wonder if there's a "better way" to query the email, I'm using aggregate because the searched key can contain a dot (`.`) in its path

and in this case, this:

```
const email = "test@gmail.com"
let account = await db.collection("users").findOne({ "createdAccounts.email": email });
```

wouldnt work.

Using the aggregate query I get as response:

```
"test@gmail.com": {
    "id": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

Suppose i need to modify the `id` array, as its inside a key containing a dot (`.`)
i couldn't find how to update it.

Also, the update method will concatenate the array or overwrite it?

Comment: FYI storing data values as a *key* is an anti-pattern and adds a lot of challenge to searches. Store as value to a well known key name like `emailAddress` or `username`.

Comment: +1 to @DavidMakogon's comment. You should store the object in tuples/objects like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vn3FbLBJhat)

Comment: The document is already in this format, i cant change it

Comment: Performance-wise, iterating the kv tuples generated from `$objectToArray` will be the canonical way to perform the update for your case. You may want to check out [$getField](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/) and [$setField](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setField/#examples) for field name with `.` inside too

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you really should use the [Attribute pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern) for this. Mongo doesn't handle "unknown keys" very well, unlike JS (and Python) where you can iterate over keys & values.

This pipeline will use your current structure to append an element in the `id` field, for the matched email:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "createdAccounts": {
        "$objectToArray": "$createdAccounts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      // replace with the `email` you want to match
      "createdAccounts.k": "test@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "createdAccounts.v.id": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          // unclear why I need this "first" but the
          // concat produces an extra array if I don't
          { "$first": "$createdAccounts.v.id" },
          ["X"]  // <-- put the element you want to add
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "createdAccounts": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$createdAccounts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "users",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "discard"
    }
  }
])
```

Note that in [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ML4PpT0FhQz) it will only show the document as per the pipeline result. The merge result can be seen by checking the updated document in the collection.

Result in the `users` collection:

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "a": "",
  "b": 1,
  "createdAccounts": {
    "test@gmail.com": {
      "id": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "X"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```